# Can't seem to plot 200,000 points with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot about 200,000 points with `geom_beeswarm`. When I plot instead of `geom_beeswarm` with geom_point I'll get the plot but this also takes about 30 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
libray(tidyverse)
library(beeswarm)

df_tidy %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = misdrijf, y = verandering_2010_2016)) +
  geom_beeswarm() +
  geom_point(data = filter(df_tidy, regio == "Nederland",
                           jaar == 2016), colour = "#FF9800") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10)) +
  annotate("text", x = "6.3 Drugsmisdrijf (overig)", y = -30, label = Annotation_layer_1.1, size = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = "9 Misdrijven overige wetten", y = -30, xend = "9.2 Misdrijf (overig)", yend = -19)) +
  annotate("text", x = "3.3.5 Pornografie", y = -20, label = Annotation_layer_1.2, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", x = "1.3.1 Muntmisdrijf", y = -20, label = Annotation_layer_1.3, size = 3) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = "1.2.2 Flessentrekkerij", y = -20, xend = "1.2 Bedrog", yend = -11.5)) +
  labs(title = "Welk misdrijf per 1000 inwoners is gegroeid of\ngedaald?",
       subtitle = subtitle_1,
       x = "",
       y = "Verandering 2016 tenopzichte van 2010")
```

My machine is a Macbook pro 2,2 GHz Intel Core i7.

Is it normal that it takes this long?

Comment: Yeah that’s essentially normal. Subsample the points for plotting. Yes, it’s annoying.

Comment: `geom_violin` might be a good alternative. It is used to show similar data, but aggregates.

Comment: Other alternatives are "letter-value" plot or just a basic histogram.

Comment: you can profile to see where the bog-down is. plotting is going to be slow but i also suspect the beeswarm code is taking a long time as well.